# Angular 6, Large data causes slow performance using Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-material-6

I am using an angular6/mat-dialog-modal to render multi/single select dropdown values synchronously (data already received from api).. The form works as expected but the performance is terribly slow when the user clicks on an actual select drop down AND when they attempt to select an item in the dropdown list. Some of the options could be up to 500-1000 items for a particular select field. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Sample Data (this.data)

```
[ // less than 30 objects in this array
 {
   id: "company1",
   label: "Amazon",
   state: {
     options: [ // could be 5000+ objects in this array
       {
         label: "Sony Playstation"
         selected: false
         value: "PS4"
       }
     ]
   },
   type: "multiSelect"
 }
]
```

Template

```
<form *ngIf="myForm" [formGroup]="myForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
  <mat-form-field *ngFor="let option of formHelper">
    <mat-label>{{ option.label }}</mat-label>

    <mat-select *ngIf="option.isMultiple" [formControlName]="option.id" disableOptionCentering multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let val of option.values" [value]="val.value">
        {{ val.label }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>

    <mat-select *ngIf="!option.isMultiple" [formControlName]="option.id" disableOptionCentering multiple>
      <mat-option [value]="option.values">
        {{ option.values }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

TypeScript

```
public rawData: any[];
public myForm: FormGroup;
public formHelper = [];

ngOnInit() {
  this.rawData = this.data
  this.constructForm()
}

private constructForm() {
  const formObj = {};

  for (let i = 0; i < this.rawData.length; i++) {
    const currObj = this.rawData[i];
    formObj[currObj['id']] = new FormControl([]);

    this.formHelper.push({
      id: currObj['id'],
      isMultiple: currObj['type'] === 'multiSelect',
      label: currObj['label'],
      values: currObj['state']['options']
    });
  }

  this.myForm = new FormGroup(formObj);
}
```

Comment: You can perform lazy loading(Eg : 50 rows, then fetch other 50 on scrolling), if user searches, then use any sorting algorithm like merge or binary.

Comment: Why not use **[Virtual Scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview)** from Angular CDK?

Comment: Do you mind creating a sample [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular) replicating this issue? I might be able to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's slow because you are adding 500 to 1000 nodes to the DOM.

I don't know of any way to make that faster, but have you considered  that a drop-down with many hundreds of choices is probably not a good user experience?

You might be able to provide a better user experience and better performance by turning this into an auto-complete instead.